# "Convert" NTFS EFI partition to FAT32

Tags: windows, partitioning, ntfs, fat32

I want to convert NTFS EFI Partion to Fat32.

I tried to install windows 10 on my windows 8.1 but unfortunately made some mistake and now I am middle of something that I am getting error while installing windows 10 that - EFI partition is NTFS formatted and you need to format it by FAT32 and restart system..

I dont want to use diskpart method that includes clean disk it will erase all drive data. I have use Rufus to create Bootbale USB. 
I have 1TB hard disk on which there are 3 drives. 
I dont want to loose my data from other drives ..

Also A simple solution that doesn't involve backing everything up would be better.

please let me know guys if there is any solutions.

Comment: First, are you sure it is actually an EFI partition? If Windows chose NTFS for it, then it most likely means it's actually the boot partition for _BIOS_ systems... (Which also means you'd need to convert MBR to GPT too.)

Comment: yes it is EFI NTFS .  I use Rufus Software for formatting the USB as MBR partition for Bios or UEFI CSM then it gets error while using this usb as bootable as it in needs o convert in GPT partition then I format drive as for GPT now it showing error that windows partition is EFI NTFS and needs to format in Fat 32. while installing windows..

Comment: UEFI CSM == “BIOS”. However, what’s on your USB drive is only marginally important. Please get the GParted Live CD and provide a screenshot of the current disk configuration.

Comment: let me do this with Gparted live CD .. I will let you know tomorrow..

Comment: I have  followed all in gparted steps on my hard disk (format System drive as Fat32 )but when try to install windows after exit it shows that partition must be formatted as NTFS and after format drive as ntfs from windows installation it shows it must be formatted as fat32 .. Its a lot of confusion .. can u help me .. we can contact via skype

Comment: Better diagnostics, as others have said, are desirable. That said, I don't know offhand of any tool that will convert from NTFS to FAT without damaging files, so you may need to back up the EFI System Partition (ESP), create a fresh FAT filesystem on it, and restore it. The ESP is normally small, so this shouldn't be a big deal. OTOH, if it's NTFS, then that suggests that something's already trashed whatever was on it before, so you may not have anything to back up. That shouldn't be a big deal if you're re-installing, though; just create a fresh FAT filesystem and move on.

Comment: I have lost all my data and other partition now by using HP recovery disk. Now my system have only 2 partition one is System and other is Recovery drive. Is there any way I can get my previous data or partition back.  Please help me guys..

Comment: @RahulDambare The EFI Partition is what must be Fat32, The rest of the HDD, must be NTFS. You can use windows tools to fix an EFI partition as whatever is in there, is not necessary to keep the same as its only purpose is to boot windows, nothing special unless you have multiple installs of windows, which you would just need to rebuild the BCD to include your other installs. Diskpart, doesn't always erase the entire drive either, you can have it erase only the partition specified, here the efi partition.